# Remaining seconds until midnight

Tags: lua

I'm trying to figure out a good way to get remaining seconds until midnight. I can think of some hacky solution with `os.date()` but is there a good function for this to go with `os.time()`?

Comment: Why do you say your `os.date` solution is hacky? You should include it with your question.

Comment: Tim Cooper, I think it could be possible to maybe add 1 minute in a loop, like: os.date( "%d", os.time() + 60 * i ) and compare with current %d, but there seems like this is not the best way

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff thank you, although it's saying 9 hours right now but it's 6 hours and 1 minute

Answer (score 1):

```
local dt = os.date("*t")
local remaining_seconds = (dt.hour * -3600 - dt.min * 60 - dt.sec) % 86400
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit the fact that the time and date library does date arithmetic:

```
dt=os.date("*t")
t0=os.time(dt)
dt.day=dt.day+1
dt.hour=0
dt.min=0
dt.sec=0
remaining_seconds=os.time(dt)-t0
```